# Why is it necessary to validate usernames?

Tags: forms, security, validation

I've been reading the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial book by Michael Hartl and he doesn't validate the username in the sample app of the book. Yet so many websites are asking users to register with only alphanumerics and underscores(not always allowed even).

I've searched for a while both on google and stack_overflow but only found huge amount of people asking how to validate username in the above manner.

Gee, why do we need to do it in the first place then?

Comment: A slight aside, but bear in mind most sample code in books are full of security holes; they only intend to teach how to achieve the functionality they demonstrate and are not intended to be polished, finished, production-ready components. OWASP is a good resource for webapp security. The top ten project is a good starting point https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once reason I can think of is to ensure they are URL friendly. Any website that has a user resource, and uses the username in the URL instead of the ID, will require a URL-safe username.

Any website that requires a username but doesn't use it as a resource probably shouldn't require a username to begin with (use email address for login instead).

EDIT:
To answer your comment: **"The space character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs."**

As per [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). This document also describes why other characters are unsafe.

Comment: In fact I've heard about URLs should not have spaces in them but always don't understand why (forgive me if this one seems common sense as I'm still a web dev newbie here :o). Besides, any other security reasons or others about it?

Comment: I've edited my answer in response to your question.

Comment: Then if I don't use username in URLs it will be totally ok right? I mean I also use user resource but use user_id in URLs instead~~

Comment: Sure, then it's not really a problem. Sounds like it's more of a 'Display Name' now as opposed to a 'username'.

Comment: Well, you are right Christian, I just want to say that -- I only want the name to be displayed...yep, should be called Display Name, more appropriate.:p Thanks soooo much for your clarification!!! Feel so warm as a newbie you know!:)

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  I think that only spaces should be disallowed in most cases.  I think the main reasons are to avoid possible problems with encoding/decoding that could open up security holes.  All of those problems can and should be solved in better ways, though.  I've seen the same with passwords, even, which is even more ridiculous (Regions will not allow special characters).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Umm, what are the problems to do with encoding/decoding then? And how to solve those problems in a better way? Could you please give me a link about that? Also, why spaces should be disallowed? Because of the URL issue mentioned by Christian below? Can't we work around that as well -- like sub spaces to '-' with regex or something~~?:)

Answer (score 0):

If usernames are supposed to be unique, what if you have two users named these?

```
John Doe
John  Doe
```

If you're putting the names straight into the HTML, they'll look identical. If you fix that, there's probably other things to be done with Unicode. Requiring a username to be alphanumeric (and maybe some other characters) solves many of these problems.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Well my point of not validating the username is exactly to let users decide any name they want to use! See I have always got this headache when the website tells me "That name has been taken~~"GEE!!! For those who just want an account for the first time visit to have a look of the site, use as many spaces as you like and change to your prime name later! Or even you think many spaces in your name is cool~~well, go with it~~nothing wrong with that after all right? I mean if I don't use username in URLs, as Christian above mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other reasons stated, allowing arbitrary Unicode characters enables one user to create a name that appears very similar to another user's name by using Unicode characters that closely resemble Latin letters, e.g.

K℮ℎ

Keh

(above renders correctly at least in Chrome on Windows 7).

On the other hand, disallowing Unicode characters creates an unnecessary bias against non-English visitors who may well have accent marks in their given name (e.g. Jürgen), or whose native language may use an alphabet not based on the Latin character set (e.g. 孔夫子).